# programming EXACT timer which calles a function in c language every x seconds

Tags: c, linux, timer, real-time

I need some help with a part of my Programm. I want to call a function **EXACTLY every x seconds**. 
The problem with the most soultions is, that the time to call the sleep() or w/e function stacks over time.

An example: If I want to call a function every second with sleep(1), it takes 1 second + a very small **x** (time to call the sleep() function). 
So it takes 1,**x** seconds. Not 1,0 second.

Over a long period of time the **x stacks to a "huge amount" of time.**

I want a code snippet which executes something EXACTLY every second so that I get exact timestamps without any additional delay.
I think it's part of the real-time-programming problem.

Is there some working code out there for that?

Please help me out with that. :)

FloKL

Comment: Linux is not a real-time operating system. For what you are trying to do, ie., get your code to run with 100% predictability, you need a proper RTOS. There something called [RTLinux][1] that provides real-time capabilities to a Linux system.


  [1]: https://www.windriver.com/products/linux/download/#product_versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int X = 10;
 int t1 = (int)time(NULL);
 while(1==1){
     // execute your process
     ...
     // calculate next tick
     t1 = t1 + X;
     sleep(t1 - (int)time(NULL));
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much! That helped me! Is there a NON-BLOCKING solution for this too? That the processor can handle his own stuff while he waits for the next execution?

Comment: @FloKl If by "non blocking" you mean "non polled, non busy waiting", then yes, any solution involving `sleep()` meets this requirement.  When you call `sleep()`, the operating system devotes minimal resources to your process, and can do other things.

Comment: One issue with this code is that it will have up to one second of "jitter". This can be avoided by calling functions such as [`gettimeofday`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) or [`clock_gettime`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clock_gettime) instead of `time`, and at the cost of having to perform more-complicated arithmetic on `struct timeval` or `struct timespec`.

Answer (score 1):

You can recode your call to sleep to pass effectively `1 - a` rather than `1` where `a` is an adjustment calculate to eliminate the accumulated `x`. (Clearly you'll need to adjust the sleep unit as `a` will be less than `1` in general).

Otherwise C provides no facility directly for an "exact" timing. You'll need to use external hardware for that. And expect to pay a lot of money for atomic-clock level accuracy.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is equal to the solution of angelito, right?

Comment: @FloKl The essential feature of a correct solution is to call `time()` (or some other function which synchronizes your program by fetching time from an external clock) each time through the loop.  angelito's answer makes this call explicit; Bathsheba's answer doesn't.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Yes that's correct. I refrained from attempting a solution as it would be in contraction with the requirement of exactness. Yes angelito's answer implements my suggestion in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

suggest using the function: `setitimer()` which is exposed via the header file: `<sys/timer.h>`.

Suggest reading the MAN page for `setitimer` for all the details